# QGIS 3.2 problem with Python console

Tags: qgis

I have QGIS Desktop 3.2.2 software already installed. When I open up the program I get the following error:

```
Plugin processing: The plugin will be disabled because it crashed QGIS during last startup. Please report an issue and re-enable the plugin when the problem has been solved.
```

When I try to open up the Python console I get another kind of error:

```
Failed to open Python console:


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\aboufira\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 16, in 
    from . import multiarray
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.2/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 674, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.2\apps\Python36\lib\code.py", line 91, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.2/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 674, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.2/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\__init__.py", line 29, in 
    from processing.tools.general import *              # NOQA
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.2/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 674, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.2/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\tools\general.py", line 39, in 
    from processing.core.Processing import Processing
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.2/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 674, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.2/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\core\Processing.py", line 58, in 
    from processing.algs.qgis.QgisAlgorithmProvider import QgisAlgorithmProvider  # NOQA
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.2/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 674, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.2/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\qgis\QgisAlgorithmProvider.py", line 82, in 
    from .HypsometricCurves import HypsometricCurves
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.2/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 674, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.2/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\qgis\HypsometricCurves.py", line 29, in 
    import numpy
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.2/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 674, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:\Users\aboufira\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 142, in 
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.2/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 674, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:\Users\aboufira\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py", line 13, in 
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.2/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 674, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:\Users\aboufira\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\numpy\lib\__init__.py", line 8, in 
    from .type_check import *
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.2/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 674, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:\Users\aboufira\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\numpy\lib\type_check.py", line 11, in 
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.2/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 674, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:\Users\aboufira\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 26, in 
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: 
Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed.  Most
likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy.
If you're working with a numpy git repo, try `git clean -xdf` (removes all
files not under version control).  Otherwise reinstall numpy.

Original error was: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred instead:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 2, in 
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.2/apps/qgis/./python\console\console.py", line 46, in show_console
    _console = PythonConsole(parent)
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.2/apps/qgis/./python\console\console.py", line 82, in __init__
    self.console = PythonConsoleWidget(self)
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.2/apps/qgis/./python\console\console.py", line 108, in __init__
    self.shell = ShellScintilla(self)
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.2/apps/qgis/./python\console\console_sci.py", line 91, in __init__
    self.runsource(line)
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.2/apps/qgis/./python\console\console_sci.py", line 665, in runsource
    return super(ShellScintilla, self).runsource(source, filename, symbol)
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.2\apps\Python36\lib\code.py", line 75, in runsource
    self.runcode(code)
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.2\apps\Python36\lib\code.py", line 95, in runcode
    self.showtraceback()
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.2\apps\Python36\lib\code.py", line 149, in showtraceback
    sys.excepthook(ei[0], ei[1], last_tb)
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.2/apps/qgis/./python\console\console_sci.py", line 661, in excepthook
    self.write("".join(traceback.format_exception(etype, value, tb)))
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.2/apps/qgis/./python\console\console_sci.py", line 645, in write
    sys.stderr.write(txt)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'


Python version:
3.6.0 (v3.6.0:41df79263a11, Dec 23 2016, 08:06:12) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]

QGIS version:
3.2.2-Bonn 'Bonn', 26842169e9

Python path:
['C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.2/apps/qgis/./python', 'C:/Users/aboufira/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\\profiles\\default/python', 'C:/Users/aboufira/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\\profiles\\default/python/plugins', 'C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.2/apps/qgis/./python/plugins', 'C:\\Program Files\\QGIS 3.2\\bin\\python36.zip', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGIS3~1.2\\apps\\Python36\\DLLs', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGIS3~1.2\\apps\\Python36\\lib', 'C:\\Program Files\\QGIS 3.2\\bin', 'C:\\Users\\aboufira\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python36\\site-packages', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGIS3~1.2\\apps\\Python36', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGIS3~1.2\\apps\\Python36\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGIS3~1.2\\apps\\Python36\\lib\\site-packages\\win32', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGIS3~1.2\\apps\\Python36\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGIS3~1.2\\apps\\Python36\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin', 'C:/Users/aboufira/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\\profiles\\default/python']
```

I also notice that in the Menu the `vector` tab is not working. I have seen many issues about this. Many of them recommended removing OsGeo install (if any) in the system. I have basically removed all other things which I think might be interfering with QGIS 3.2.2 including:

- All other versions of QGIS
- OsGeo64
- Python36 by Anaconda (but this still did not remove the python36 directory in `C:\Users\aboufira\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py` from which the Python console issue seems to begin)

What is the problem with the QGIS 3.2.2 program? How can I fix these issues?
(Do I need to reset my Python path?)